# Google Website Translator provokes mixed content error

Tags: https, google-translate

Since yesterday, I got mixed content errors on my website in both Chrome and IE. The error is provoked by the Google Translate script included in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I downloaded the file element.js and eventually figured out where the bug comes from:

```
var s = window.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https' : 'http';
```

Using (any) browser console, we can see that the expression "window.location.protocol" returns "https:" (and not "http") in all secure websites. Therefore, the script tries to load a bunch of CSS/JavaScript resources it needs, prefixing their URL with "http" instead of "https".

Which results in the following errors (one per resource):

```
The page at https://mysite.com ran insecure content from http://translate.googleapis.com/[something].css
```

The Google Translate tool is really useful to my users so I cannot remove it. Also, I tried to download the script and run it locally but it doesn't work. I spent a lot of time on that issue, am I the only one in that situation or something changed recently in the Google Translate script?

**[EDIT]**

I just took a look at the Google Analytics code and found that:

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www');
```

This reinforces the idea that the Google Translate script should test for "https:" too.

Comment: Here is the offending line of code: `var s = (false ? 'https' : window.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https' : 'http') + '://';` This always resolves to using `http://`. I tried to make a bug report but finding where to do so is amazingly difficult. That code comes from: `https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit`. Bug report here: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/webmaster-tools/FC_YrmUI7YY

Comment: I just noticed that Chrome 28 returns `https:` for `window.location.protocol` on a secure connection, not `https` like the JS is checking for... (notice the colon)

Comment: If you read my post, you will see that I wrote exactly the same thing :) But thank you for your help, let me know if you get an answer!